What is this swinging circuit, made up of LC circuit and AC booster, called?
The first self-sustaining swinging circuit I learned of is Colpitt’s oscillator. This circuit uses a capacitive voltage splitter. I thought it should be possible to make a self-sustaining swinging circuit which contains a simple LC circuit made up of a single inductor and a single capacitor, an oscillator which doesn’t make use of any capacitive or inductive voltage division. So I tried and succeeded to come up with such a swinger. I looked in thought to an actual swing for inspiration and thereby found that the oscillator could be realized by at each time point boosting the voltage of the tank circuit in the direction which it has at that time point. I realized that an AC amplifier would do the trick. So I fed the voltage of the tuned circuit into the input of the AC booster and fed the latter’s output back into the resonant circuit. Here’s the diagram of the circuit I drew up and built:

With the values for capacitance, inductance, and parasitic resistance given in the diagram, the circuit swang at approximately 104 kHz. Then, I played around with the LC circuit a bit. By removing the 6.8 nF capacitor, I achieved ca. 333 kHz. It seems the springs of my circuit board have enough parasitic capacitance. I switched the inductor out for a solenoid spool and thereby achieved about 833 kHz. Finally, by putting an iron core into the spool, I reached around 1.25 MHz. The differential equation for an LC circuit is:
$$\frac{1}{C}Q(t) = -\dot{Q}(t)R - \ddot{Q}(t)L \text{,}$$
which is equivalent to
$$\ddot{Q}(t) + \frac{R}{L}\dot{Q}(t) + \frac{1}{LC}Q(t) = 0 \text{.}$$
This shows that the resonant circuit swings for $$R < 2 \sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}$$ at a frequency of
$$f = \frac{1}{2\pi} \sqrt{\frac{1}{LC} - \frac{R^2}{4 L^2}} \text{.}$$
For the values shown on the diagram, this gives us about 117 kHz, which fits well with the aforesaid measured value of 104 kHz. The forecast is a bit too high probably because the capacitance is really a bit higher than 6.8 nF due to the abovementioned parasitic capacitance. The matching between forecast and measured valued shows that it's really the LC circuit that swings.
I need the potentiometer to adjust the resistance between the first transistor and the second precisely. When the resistance is too high, the swinging dies down. When it’s too low, the oscillations are distorted due to clipping. By hitting the sweet spot in the middle, I get nice sinusoidal waves.
A good feature my circuit shares with Colpitt's is that it's self-startig; it begins to swing on its own.
It may help if you construct my circuit yourself and test it.
I looked for different swinging circuits on Wikipedia but found none which don’t use inductive or capacitive voltage splitting. Considering that my circuit is the simplest I can think of (it’s just an LC circuit and an AC amplifier forming a positive feedback loop), I’m pretty sure it already has a name. So, what is this circuit called?
And why does it seem to be seldom used? A possible explanation I can think of is that the need for fine tuning with the variable resistor indicates my swinging circuit isn’t very stable. Is this correct?

@greybeard It would be an astable multivibrator without the resonant circuit. However, the latter is the heart piece of my circuit, so my circuit differs in a key way from an astable. My swinging circuit reaches such high frequencies only thanks to the LC circuit. I've edited my question to highlight the crucial role of the tank circuit.

(too low … clipping … sweet spot … nice sinusoidal waves what's the voltage swing?)

@greybeard What exactly do you mean? "Voltage swing" is a good name for the LC circuit , but I used the noun "swing" in another way in my question. I wrote that I looked to a mechanical swing for some inspiration.

(voltage swing is used for minimum and maximum voltage, or the difference between; often at one node of interest in a circuit with reference to ground, even without-periodic signals (as in rail-to-rail op-amp). In an oscillator, voltage swing with limited distortion ideally isn't much lower than when including saturation/clipping.)

Looks like a Franklin oscillator. The tank circuit (L1, C1) is usually coupled lightly (C2, C4 very small), without the need for R1, to the in and output of the two inverting amplifier stages.

@greybeard Oh, thanks   for the clarification! Good to learn a term I didn't know before . With the parameters in the diagram, the voltage swing with clipping is only a little higher than with sine waves.

@Raonoke Thank you   for basically answering my question! I just ecosied and googled "Franklin oscillator" and found that this swinger is indeed essentially the same as mine. Should C2 and C4 be very small so that only high frequencies get through? I found http://www.arthropodsystems.com/FranklinOscillator/FranklinOscillator.html, but there, my R1 is present (and the resistor to be varied). Can we really do without R1?

"swinging circuit" is not a standard name for an oscillator, nor for an LC tank circuit.

In English, the word is "oscillator"; "swinger" means something very different.

@Raonoke -  Thanks for helping, but please avoid answering a question in comments - that is not an allowed use of comments :( Please consider moving that comment into an actual answer. TY (Please see here for why answering in a comment can be harmful & here for more details of the allowed uses of comments.)

Below an example for a low frequency (~500kHz) Franklin oscillator. To move the center frequency up or down adjust the value of L1. Chosen inductor Q is around 73. Two resistors R7, R8 (18k) isolate, together with two small 100pF caps, the LC tank circuit from the amplifier and ensure that maximum loop gain coincides with 0°(360°) phase shift. Instead of having the amplifier limiting the output voltage, two Schottky diodes (D1, D2) are used to do the job instead.
Schematic:

Output voltage and voltage across the LC tank circuit:

Overall loop gain is just above 4 at 0° phase shift:


Thank you for your detailed and informative answer  ! The Schottkies are there to make the clipping clean and symmetrical, ✅️?

Yes, the diodes are responsible for the constant and clean looking output voltage. The two amplifying stages are kept operating in linear mode.

Thank you for the info! A neat little circuit indeed! Will upvote your answer once I hit 15 rep.

What happens with big C3 and C4? Mine works pretty well with 10 μF each.

The two 18k (R7, R8) resistors already provide excellent isolation and by increasing C3,C4 to e.g. 10uF nothing worth mentioning will happen besides the frequency moving down a couple of kHz. Those two resistors are not always used, especially at much higher frequencies, in which case C3,C4 will be made as small as possible.  In your circuit, because of C4=10uF, the LC tank circuit is directly loaded with resistor R4 (470 Ohm) affecting Q.

Now I understand .
